# Building dynamic Regex using Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala, dynamic

Am somewhat new to Scala, however, its not my first programming rodeo. I am reading in from a file, Regex commands to be applied to a database. I dynamically build the regex as follows:

```
var valueRegex = new StringBuilder
var eRegex = z(3).toString() // comes from the third column in the file I am reading into the program.

valueRegex ++= "\"\"\" "
valueRegex ++= eRegex
valueRegex ++= " \"\"\""
valueRegex ++= ".r"

var allRegex = valueRegex
```

I have tried casting valueRegex to a string, char, etc. No luck. I want to just issue this command as follows:

```
println((allRegex findAllIn impression).mkString(",")) // impression field in DB.
```

It is printing the allRegex correctly and if I cut/paste it into a static variable - all works.

---

More code as follows:

```
    var eRegex = None: Option[String]
    var valueRegex = new StringBuilder
    var allRegex = None: Option[CharSequence]


    for (a <- z) {

      if ( z(3).isEmpty() ) {
       var eRegex : String = (z(0))

       valueRegex ++= "\"\"\""
       valueRegex ++= eRegex
       valueRegex ++= "\"\"\""
       valueRegex ++= ".r"

       // var allRegex = valueRegex
       val allRegex = eRegex.r

       println(allRegex)

       // println(eRegex)
      } else {
       var eRegex = z(3).toString()
       valueRegex ++= "\"\"\" "
       valueRegex ++= eRegex
       valueRegex ++= " \"\"\""
       valueRegex ++= ".r"

       // var allRegex = valueRegex
       val allRegex = eRegex.r

       println(allRegex)
      }

      println("Record ID: " + id + "\n") 
      ***println((allRegex findAllIn impression).mkString(","))***
```

I am still getting the same error: value FindAllIn is not a member of Option[Sequence]

When I create a variable foo = """""".r it gets evaluated fine in the println statement.

Ok, here is the solution as follows:

```
       val allRegex = eRegex.r.findAllIn(impression).mkString(",")
       println(allRegex)
```

Thanks to reggert and cdshines for their help and insight!

Answer (score 2):

Scala is not a dynamic language, but you appear to be trying to treat it as such by attempting to evaluate strings as Scala code, which you can only do by instantiating an interpreter from within your code (which is way too complicated for what you want to do).

Just do this:

```
val allRegex = eRegex.r
```

This will give you an instance of the Regex class. Consult the documentation for this class to figure out how to use it to do pattern matching on the strings that you want to search.

Comment: These two lines fixed the problem as follows:

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what precisely is your problem, but I guess it's something like `error: value findAll is not a member of String`. Am I right?

The thing is, you are appending `".r"` to the regex itself instead of calling `.r` on the `String` instance. Look:

```
scala> val vr = """\s.r"""
vr: String = \s.r

scala> vr findAllIn " "
<console>:9: error: value findAllIn is not a member of String
              vr findAllIn " "
                 ^

scala> val vr = """\s""".r
vr: scala.util.matching.Regex = \s

scala> vr findAllIn " "
res2: scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator = non-empty iterator
```

I hope you can deduce the correct solution from here. If you want something more concrete, share some concrete code + error snippet.

Comment: Tried the code: val allRegex = eRegex.r and still get the error value findAllIn is not a member of Option[CharSequence]

Comment: Well then, you are calling your method on an `Option[_]` instead of a regex. Please post SSCCE: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: cdshines, Thanks for your quick reply! Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what precisely is your problem, but if You want to Build a Dynamic Regexp using Scala, then String interpolation could help, e.g.:

```
val x = "abc" // this could be dynamic

val pattern = s"^$x([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$$".r

pattern.findAllMatchIn("abc2022-01-19").foreach(x=>println(x))
```

prints

```
abc2022-01-19
```